# how to get notified when the ble device linkloss occurs

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am new to bledevice.Please help me, how can I get notified ,when the ble device link loss occurs.I need to do some stuffs in android when the device link loss occcurs.

Currently I can get notified ,when the device is connected and disconnected using Broadcast receiver.

And I know the service for link loss 0x1803
and bluetooth Gatt characteristic is 00002A06-0000-******-*******-****34F

But I dont know how to use this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You will receive the onConnectionStateChange callback when the peripheral disconnects with newState set to STATE_DISCONNECTED.